# Issue with LostFocus event of a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox

I'm trying to use this function:

```
private void IDCustTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
      if (CustName.Text == "abc")
          MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

When I type abc in `CustName` textbox, and then leave the textbox, I dont get any message. In the textbox properties I can see that "textbox.Changed" is using the event LostFocus.

How can I get this to show the Error message above?

Comment: I guess you have not attached this to the event `CustTextBox.LostFocus += new EventHandler(IDCustTextBox_LostFocus);` this event is not shown in the properties window

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no LostFocus event for textbox in **property Window**,if you want to use this then you must need to add event handler, there is textbox leave event in property window, that could be used as below:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // do your stuff
    }
```

for adding event handler you need to write the following:

```
textBox1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_LostFocus);
```

then you can use it as below:

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // do your stuff
    }
```

Comment: This is not true it is [just not shown in the properties window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx)

Comment: TextBox inherits from Control and as such it inherits LostFocus.

Comment: you are not in any way generating a custom event, just adding a handler for the existing event

Answer (score 5):

You will need to let the field know that there is a handler for the event `LostFocus`

Since this is [not part of the properties window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) you will have attach the handler as such

```
CustTextBox.LostFocus += new EventHandler(IDCustTextBox_LostFocus);
```

Comment: Work , thanks 

But i want to ask you , i want to know why i need to use this handler , when i need to use it and when not ?

Comment: In case of events in the properties window this part is automatically done (you can see that in the designer.cs file of the form) while in cases as this you will have to do that part. This actually helps in knowing that `LostFocus` will be handled by this method